# "click" doesn't work on all mobiles idk why

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive

i'm working on a web app with vue and vuetify and i'm confront a little issue and i really don't know where does the problem come from.

my web app works fine on desktop but on mobile i dont know why i cant click on certains elements.
when I say certain elements, these are the elements that have the v-on click directive,
I tested on different mobiles and I don't understand why it's not the same buttons that have the same problem.

if button A works on mobile A, on mobile B it does not work:

thanks in advance

````
<template>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="brand_name">
                <h2>Shop<span>X</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="part2">
                <p :class="error.token ? 'err' : 'ok' ">{{ error }}</p>
                <form  class="form" action="">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="phone" required="" v-model="loginModel.tel" autocomplete="off">
                        <label>
                            <span style="transition-delay:0ms">P</span><span style="transition-delay:0ms">h</span><span style="transition-delay:50ms">o</span><span style="transition-delay:100ms">n</span><span style="transition-delay:150ms">e</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="password" required="" v-model="loginModel.pass">
                        <label>
                            <span style="transition-delay:0ms">P</span><span style="transition-delay:50ms">a</span><span style="transition-delay:100ms">s</span><span style="transition-delay:150ms">w</span><span style="transition-delay:200ms">o</span><span style="transition-delay:250ms">r</span><span style="transition-delay:300ms">d</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button class="button" @click="Login">Connexion</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="back-home">
            <RouterLink to="/">← Retour au menu</RouterLink>
          </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

// set the token just 

import { RouterLink, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import Axios from '../services/callerServices';
import { ref } from 'vue';
const router = useRouter();

let loginModel = {
    tel: undefined,
    pass: undefined
}

let error = ref('')

const Login = async (req, res) => {
    let user = {
        nom: loginModel.tel,
        password: loginModel.pass
    }
    try {
        let res = Axios.post('/Login', {
            telephone: user.nom,
            password: user.password,
        })
        let parsedResponse = await res

        if (!parsedResponse.data.token) {
            error.value = parsedResponse.data
            console.log(error.value);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('token', parsedResponse.data.token)
            console.log('mtn');
            error.value = 'Bienvenue' + parsedResponse.data.user.nom + ' ' + parsedResponse.data.user.prenom
            setTimeout(() => {
                router.push('/dashboard')
            }, 800)
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);

    }

} 
</script>```
````

Comment: you can try make a minimal example on codesandbox?

Comment: i have a lot of dependencies

Comment: you don't need a full reproduction.  just enough to minimally reproduce the issue.  this problem could potentially be reproduced with a single div with an onclick event that executes a simple console.log.  If that does **not** reproduce the issue, add more code matching your app until it does.  this is the basis of creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would also like to know if the issue is consistent.  does it never work on device B or just sometimes?  is it always the same button or is the behavior more "random"?  what specific devices/OS/browsers are you working with?

Comment: @yoduh it's totally random, i tried it on safari for iphone